# Am I moving or cloning this String

Tags: rust

I have an enum defined like this:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub enum JsonState {
    NameReadingState(String),
    StringState(String),
}

impl JsonState {
    pub fn get_name_read(self) -> String {
        if let JsonState::NameReadingState(name) = self {
            return name;
        } else {
            panic!(
                "Error: attempted to get name from non name state {:#?}",
                self
            );
        }
    }
}
```

If I were to call `get_name_read` on an instance of `JsonState` would the string  be moved out of the enum or would it be copied? My understanding is that since I am passing `self` and not `&self` I am taking ownership of the instance inside the function and so I should be able to simply move the string out of it.

Comment: Note that the explicit return is not idiomatic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It is moved.**

This is, in my opinion, one of the great advantages of Rust over C++: if you don't see a `.clone()` anywhere, then you are not cloning! In Rust, there are no implicit deep copies like in C++. If you want to create a copy/clone then you have to do it explicitly by calling a method that clones your instance.

All of this comes with one exception: types that implement [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Copy.html). These types use copy semantics instead of move semantics. It should be noted that `Copy` can only be implemented for types "whose values can be duplicated simply by copying bits", i.e. very simple types. `String` and any other types that manage heap memory do not implement `Copy`.

Comment: _if you don't see a .clone(), then you are not cloning!_  Generalizing like this may not be correct due to struct may have an implementation of `Copy` trait.

Comment: @ÖmerErden Thanks! Somehow I completely forgot to mention that. Very good point. I edited my answer to explain that.